# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x1b4520df0) to 'NSString'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child((uid)!)

            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                    let htest = dictionary["h"] as! String //error is mainly here signal SIGABRT

                    var inthtest = Int(htest)

                    if (inthtest==0){
                        self.checkPointsk()
                        print("scanning1")
```

I've tried changing the as String Value To int Value but it still doesn't work

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 not really ;//

Comment: then print your dictionary and post it

Comment: After changing as! String to as! Int .. it runs the first time and updates it to the database but the second time it shows this error . FirebaseSocialLogin[1954:851767] Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x1b45216b0) to 'NSNumber' (0x1b4531c00).
(lldb)  @ElCaptainv2.0

Comment: Can you please post a snippet of your Firebase structure as TEXT please, NO images so we can take a look at what is contained in the snapshot?

Answer (score 3):

The error is self explanatory. You're trying to cast a number as a string. Replace the below two lines

```
let htest = dictionary["h"] as! String 
var inthtest = Int(htest)
```

with

```
var inthtest = dictionary["h"] as! Int
```

The best way to avoid crashes like this is to use conditional binding.

```
if var inthtest = dictionary["h"] as? Int{
    //Do your stuff
}
else if var inthtest = dictionary["h"] as? String{
    if let integerValue = Int(inthtest){
        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: is not a int it is number

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Why use NSNumber in Swift? NSNumber can be cased as Int without any problem. It's better to use Swift data types like Int,Double, etc over NSNumber.

Comment: @ebby94 FirebaseSocialLogin[1951:850597] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value this is the error i get , when i do as you told me too. like i said ive already tried replacing String with Int

Comment: @ZahidAhmed Seems like that value is not consistent. It can be string or Int is what I understand. Check the updated answer(last part with conditional binding) on how to handle both the scenarios.

Comment: You aren't doing it right then. You're force casting a nil value. Read about conditional binding of Optional values.